# Can't get into insert mode in Vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim

So, I come back to my computer after the weekend and when I try to edit a file in vim now I can't get into insert mode at all. Used to be just by pressing <kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. The <kbd>Insert</kbd> key doesn't do it either.

I don't know much about vim, I haven't knowingly changed any settings.

Any idea what's gone wrong? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

My `/etc/vim/vimrc` file (minus comments) looks like:

```
runtime! debian.vim

if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif
```

I don't have a `vimrc.local` file but there is a `vimrc.tiny` which contains:

```
set runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after

set compatible
```

Both are identical to the same files on a remote server where vim behaves normally.

Comment: What abount `I` or `R`? Also try `mv ~/.vimrc ~/.vimrc.bak` before starting vim.

Comment: do you mean `shift+i` and `shift+r`?  They don't put me in insert mode either. And I don't have any `~/.vimrc` file to move.

Comment: What about `/etc/vim/vimrc`?

Comment: have added details of my vimrc file to the question above

Comment: The file or the partition that the file is on has become readonly?

Comment: Do you use vi compatibility mode? Try the command `:set nocompatible`. In contrast to vim, in vi the insert mode notification is not shown on the status line - so if you press `i` you actually _are_ in insert mode but perhaps you just don't know it. Also, does a `~/.vimrc` exist on the remote server where vim behaves normally?

Comment: @speakr thanks... `:set nocompatible` did give me normal vim back! But how do I make it 'stick'? I tried adding `set nocompatible` in `/etc/vim/vimrc` but it didn't help (feel free to reply as an answer) (there was no `~/.vimrc` on the server, no)

Comment: you can use vim -N

Comment: I was making a terrible I was writing `:i` but instead I had to write `i`. The `:` was the problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you use vi compatibility mode? Try the command `:set nocompatible`.

In vi the insert mode notification is not shown on the status line (in contrast to vim) – so if you press <kbd>i</kbd> you actually *are* in insert mode but perhaps you just don't know it.

To save user-defined settings just put them in your `~/.vimrc` (create if not existing), e.g. like:

```
set nocompatible
```

Comment: thanks, that works! I didn't recognise insert mode when I was still stuck in vi compatibility mode, because it still does 'weird vi stuff' when you try and edit the content of the file (I'm not a vimmer...)

Comment: You (=Anentropic) may not (yet) be a vimmer (please, do persist: you'll be happy you did), but you sure got a Winner (=speakr) ^^

Comment: I still hate vim

Answer (score 1):

```
syntax on
set nocompatible
```

I am compiling vim 7.3 from source and still found it was the vi editor working even after using vim command. So, to have the same effect as I normally do apt-get install vim is .. follow the above post by @speakr